# Not able to post to Facebook using custom-ui project of socialauth-android project

Tags: facebook, socialauth

I am not able to post Facebook using the `custom-ui` project of `socialauth-android`.

Here is the error log.

```
10-31 13:18:05.124: D/SocialAuthError(21880): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Status not updated. Return Status code :403
10-31 13:18:05.124: W/System.err(21880): org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthError: Message Not Posted
10-31 13:18:05.124: W/System.err(21880):    at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter$6.run(SocialAuthAdapter.java:868)
10-31 13:18:05.124: W/System.err(21880):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am not able to find the issue. I am using the same API keys got from the Github source.

Comment: How can the error be reproduced, when you didn't share any code?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 403 `Authentication Error` that clearly means that your app is presently not *authorized* to publish on Facebook profile of the user.

There is some problem the way you are trying to use Facebook APIs. I would suggest you to the latest Facebook SDK for Android as some of the older methods may be deprecated. Let me tell you the approach for doing this right way. (I recently implemented latest Facebook SDK)

- **You need a permission**

There are some specific permissions that you require to do some specific operations with Facebook SDK. For example, You need `publish_actions` permission if you want your app to post status on user's profile.

[Check Out](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) It says,

`For example, the publish_actions permission lets you post to a person's Facebook Timeline.`

- **How to get Permissions**

You need to show the user a login button which will ask him to do login with his facebook account and notifying the user what your app may do with his Facebook profile. It will show the permissions. In your case you need to add a login button with `publish_actions` permission. Once the user accepts it, your app becomes **authorized** to post status.

[Complete Tutorial is here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0) for doing the login process of Facebook with permissions.

You will need to do the following,

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status", "publish_actions"));
return view;
```

So you can see we are asking the user to give you the publish_actions permission. It is not mandatory to include `user_likes` or `user_status` permissions. You can remove them if you don't need them.

- **Next what after login**

After the user logs in, you get an `authentication token` in your `session` with Facebook. So now you can use that to publish on user's profile.

- **How to post**

Now there are many ways to publish posts or status on Facebook. The first one I would like to discuss is using the `Graph API`

Here is somewhat code, you can use to publish to facebook.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

new Request(
    session,
    "/me/feed",
    null,
    HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```

**NOTE**

You do also need to create developer account with facebook and add your app to its dashboard, generate an app_id and mention the same in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.